# PHP Web page (code) access security

Tags: code-access-security

How do I prevent my page say 'index.php' and all other web pages in different folders on server to be accessed anyone by typing the path in address bar of browser like www.kkweb.com/web/index.php. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have php correctly installed and running, they get the parsed site. I.e., they can open the website, but cannot read your source code. If you want to avoid even that, you can implement access protection. Google .htpasswd and .htaccess for that.